# Peut-on omettre « pour » dans « pour ne pas dire » ?

Tags: grammaire, anglais, expressions, prépositions

J'ai pris note de [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6653/when-to-use-pour-and-the-infinitive-or-just-the-infinitive), mais pour se servir de la tournure [*pour ne pas dire*](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/dire/25766/locution?q=pour+ne+pas+dire#170988), est-ce que *pour* est obligatoire ? Pourquoi ?

La traduction anglaise de cette expression ne le renferme pas : *<s>for</s> not to mention/say*.

Et voici [un exemple de Voltaire](http://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:D%E2%80%99Alembert_-_%C5%92uvres_compl%C3%A8tes,_%C3%A9d._Belin,_V.djvu/103) :

> Vous sentez bien, mon cher maître, que je ne fais en tout ceci que vous proposer mes doutes ; je sais très médiocrement l’anglais ; je n’ai point l’orginal sous les yeux ; la présomption est pour vous à tous égards ; et moi-même tout le premier je parierais pour vous contre moi : mais comme l’anglais et le français sont deux langues vivantes, et dans lesquelles, par conséquent, on connaît parfaitement ce qui est bas ou noble, propre ou impropre, sérieux ou familier, il est très important que dans votre traduction vous ayez conservé partout le caractère de l’original dans chaque phrase, afin que les Anglais ne vous reprochent pas ou d’ignorer la valeur des expressions dans leur langue, ou d’avoir défiguré leur idole, **pour ne pas dire** leur magot.

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord avec toi quand tu dis que l'anglais ne « renferme pas » l'équivalent du « pour » dans cette tournure, le français **pour** et l'anglais **to** introduisent ici tous les deux la notion d'intention, de but. Dans ce cas français et anglais sont bien calqués l'un sur l'autre (sauf bien sûr qu'il faut tenir compte de l'ordre des mots et du fait que la négation est double en français). Peut-être pourrais-tu reformuler ta question pour la faire porter sur les différents sens du mot **pour** en français ?

Answer (score 2):

*Pour* exprime ici le but. Les expressions française et anglaise sont en fait similaires : en anglais, *to* exprime le but. On peut considérer que « j'utilise cette tournure » est sous-entendu :

> ou d'avoir défiguré leur idole, et j'utilise ce mot pour ne pas dire « leur magot »

Grammaticalement, le groupe verbal « ne pas dire leur magot » est introduit par la préposition « pour », ce qui lui donne un sens de but. « Pour ne pas dire leur magot » est ainsi un complément circonstanciel de but.

On ne peut pas omettre la préposition *pour* (pas plus qu'on ne peut omettre *to* en anglais), sans lui la phrase n'aurait plus de sens.

Comment: @LePressentiment C'est une question d'anglais, là. La particule *to* est souvent enseignée comme faisant partie de l'infinitif, mais ce n'est en fait pas toujours le cas. On peut avoir un infinitif sans *to*, qui se trouve être précédé de *to* ayant un autre rôle.

Comment: Merci de votre réponse. Je reste désemparé. La particule *to*, fait-elle partie ici de **ne pas dire** ? Toutefois, je pensais qu'il existe déjà un *"to"* dans l'infinitive : **ne pas dire** = "not TO say". Encore, il me paraît que **pour ne pas dire** = "TO not TO say" ? SVP, prière de répondre dans votre réponse et non pas en tant que commentaire.

Comment: @LePressentiment Ça devient une question de grammaire anglaise. On enseigne souvent *to* comme faisant partie de l'infinitif en anglais, mais ce n'est pas une bonne manière de présenter les choses. Tu peux poser des questions d'anglais sur [ell.se].

Comment: À votre bon cœur ! Hélas, je reste déconcerté. Sans allusion à l'anglais, la phrase sans *pour*, pourquoi n'aurait-elle aucuns sens ? Veuillez répliquer dans votre réponse propre et non pas en tant que commentaire, histoire de garder unifie le contenu.

Comment: @LePressentiment J'ai rajouté une analyse grammaticale. On ne peut pas enlever un mot au hasard dans une phrase ! Ici, « répliquer » ne convient pas, ce verbe ne veut dire « répondre » que dans certaines circonstances qui impliquent une contradiction, on ne peut pas l'utiliser pour « répondre à une question ».

Comment: Hélas, même après tous ces mois, je n'embrasse point la nécessité du `pour` ?  . Pour résoudre mon enchevêtrement, y a-t-il une autre façon de l'apercevoir ? Je vous prie de répondre votre reponse propre et non pas à titre de commentaire SVP, histoire de garder unifié le contenu.