# The phrase "X, pour ne pas dire Y"

Tags: expressions

> Ce qu'ils ont découvert est troublant, **pour ne pas dire** effrayant.

I’m not sure which of the following two interpretations is more accurate:

1. disturbing, even if it is not to the extent of being frightening
2. disturbing, and it might even be frightening

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This rhetorical device can be called [preterition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/preterition), not to say [euphemism](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/euphemism). Your first  version does not seem correct to me. The second gets the meaning. With my limited ability in English,  if not clumsily, you would propose simpler versions:

1. disturbing, not to say frightening,
2. disturbing, if not frightening.

---

For the sake of completeness, recalling some definitions from http://www.oxforddictionaries.com:

> - [preterition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/preterition): The action of passing over or disregarding a matter, especially the rhetorical technique of making summary mention
>     of something by professing to omit it
> - [euphemism](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/euphemism): A mild or indirect word or expression substituted for one considered to be too harsh or blunt when referring to
>     something unpleasant or embarrassing

Comment: To @Laurent Duval: So is the phrase "pour ne pas dire" close in meaning to "troublant, et il **pourrait même** être effrayant"? Or is it more like "troublant, et il **peut même** être effrayant"? Merci.

Comment: @LUNA there is no "possibility" connotation, you're not saying "des fois, il peut être effrayant", you're saying you're not sure how to describe it, meaning something between "troublant" and "effrayant". With this structure, "troublant" is what sounds natural to describe him, and "effrayant" is a bit more surprising, but close to reality... "pour ne pas dire" means you don't want (at first) to use the next word because it may be too strong...

Comment: I understand both a rhetorical and a subjective part: the locutor could be utterly terrified, but mildens his sentence. In your sentence, it looks like a second-hand testimony. The locutor may mean that the "stuff" is disturbing" for most (as a fact), but could be, or become frightening for some others, possibly himself.

Answer (score 2):

En complément à une [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/21553) où l'on parle du sens et de la [prétérition](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4093) comme figure de style, on peut ajouter qu'on retrouve ce genre de syntagme prépositionnel dans le *TLFi* sous [*pour*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pour). On l'y classe sous **III** (*Entre dans une relation de causalité*).**A** (*Marque la causalité finale, le [but](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/7944)*).**2** (*Suivi d'un syntagme infinitif*).**a** (*Complément circonstanciel. Synonyme de afin de (ce dernier appartenant à la langue écrite)*).**γ** (*Dans un commentaire métalinguistique*). Donc avec *pour ne pas dire*, ça devient un peu comme dire quelque chose (de faible) afin de ne pas dire quelque chose de plus fort, donc l'idée d'atténuation de l'[euphémisme](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=%C3%A9uph%C3%A9misme&T3.x=0&T3.y=0), emballée dans une figure où l'on vend la mèche à dessein, du terme qu'on aurait ainsi évité avec l'euphémisme. Ou autrement dit, on se rapproche du [*voire*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/voire) littéraire (*difficile, voire très difficile*), et de son idée de surenchère, mais en sortant un peu du fil du discours (on parle de comment on parle, d'où le [*métalinguistique*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/m%C3%A9talinguistique))... C'est en fait de cette manière que [*Larousse*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/dire/25766/locution?q=pour%20ne%20pas%20dire#170988) en ligne la présente (*introduit une expression plus forte*).

---

Plus généralement, le *LBU14* note par ailleurs l'emploi de syntagmes prépositionnels avec l'infinitif, dont certains avec *pour*, en élément incident de phrase « pour accompagner une formulation que le lecteur pourrait trouver critiquable. » (voir Proust). En termes de construction, on peut aussi vouloir introduire un complément de phrase (voir Cocteau) :

> Elle que j'avais vue si économe, **pour** ne pas dire avare, me donnait
>   plus d'argent que je n'en demandais, me poussait à la dépense.
>   (Mauriac)
> [...] **Pour** être exact, Élisabeth y avait pensé une heure.
>   (Cocteau)
>  Le citoyen ainsi défini est à la fois « législateur et
>   sujet », **pour** parler comme Kant. (Bergson)
>  Le temps [...] insaisissable,
>   s'était pour que **pour** ainsi dire je puisse le voir et le toucher,
>   matérialisé en elle. (Proust)
>
> [ Exemples tirés du TLFi et dans *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et
>   Goosse, ed. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, §378f ]

Certaines locutions sont à rapprocher de l'emploi en prétérition, comme [*il va sans dire*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4804) pour *il va de soi*, qui en tête de phrase peut servir à introduire une proposition, en tournure impersonnelle. Avec certaines locutions, il faudra nuancer avec un emploi adverbial : « L'enquête n'a pour ainsi dire rien révélé. » (*Grand dictionnaire enc. Larousse* à ainsi, dit LBU14 §990) [presque rien].

Comment: Merci pour toutes ces précisions